# Should I access a C library from Matlab through `loadlibrary` or through a MEX file?

Tags: c, matlab, dll, mex

I need to use a shared library (DLL) developed in C from MATLAB, and I wonder what the difference is between using the `loadlibrary` function, and implementing the functions from the C library in a MEX file?

Answer (score 2):

The [loadlibray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-c-library-functions.html) function enables you to call functions from an existing C library through a foreign function interface.  [MEX file functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-file-functions.html), in contrast, is a mechanism to write functions in C (or C++, Fortran) that can be called just as regular Matlab functions.

Now one typical use pattern is to write MEX functions that *wrap* existing C functions from a foreign library (and link these MEX files to the library).  That requires a bit of work and care though, because you will have to write the wrapper function in C yourself.  A useful starting point to is the timestwo [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-an-executable-mex-file.html).

But if all you need is to call a specific function from your C library, and no intermittent transformation of input/output data is needed, the `loadlibrary` path is probably the easier one.